# Fitting data to a parametric equation

Tags: fitting, parametric-functions, nonlinear

I have a list of data pair and want to fit it to a parametric equation.
The parametric equation is:

$h(a) = \frac{a^2}{R}-\sqrt{\frac{2\pi a w}{E^*}}$

$P(a) = \frac{4a^3E^*}{3R}-\sqrt{8\pi a E^* w}$

where $R = 25\times10^{-6}$. The fitting parameters are $E^*$ and $w$, which are both positive. A good initial guess of them is $E^* = 7.5\times 10^5$ and $w = 0.025$.

The $h$ and $P$ data points are as follows.

```
hvec=1.*^-9*{-543.788, -534.501, -522.833, -505.644, -487.923, -474.96, -460.52, -442.36, -424.588, -408.419, -394.821, -377.307, -360.71, -346.718, -325.011, -300.86, -282.9, -262.037, -246.88, -224.863, -211.286, -193.259, -175.539, -154.332, -132.628, -113.743, -93.71, -72.768, -46.825, -21.77, 7.576, 30.174, 56.659, 84.041, 106.232, 128.223, 153.729, 183.145, 217.012, 246.052, 270.311, 299.043, 326.504, 345.172, 358.411}
Pvec=1.*^-6*{-0.144, -0.243, -0.354, -0.464, -0.589, -0.705, -0.818, -0.936, -1.052, -1.178, -1.284, -1.394, -1.501, -1.608, -1.743, -1.872, -1.972, -2.051, -2.112, -2.203, -2.273, -2.328, -2.406, -2.5, -2.58, -2.651, -2.741, -2.835, -2.944, -3.003, -3.041, -3.077, -3.13, -3.156, -3.163, -3.151, -3.105, -3.066, -2.98, -2.879, -2.8, -2.711, -2.586, -2.462, -2.336}
ListPlot[Thread[{hvec,Pvec}], Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: I'm missing the datapoints for the parameter a. If you have datatriples {...,{ai,h[ai],P[ai]} ,...} you can solve your problem using NonlinearModelFit[]...

Comment: What do you know about the parameters w, E*?  Probably w>0, E*>0

Comment: Thank you, @UlrichNeumann. I have updated my question with the initial guess of  $E^*$ and $w$. Since $a$ is a parametric parameter, the data points of $a$ is not known.

Comment: Please write the equations using inline code. You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window.  It is recommended that you browse [the Markdown help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1584/how-to-copy-code-from-mathematica-so-it-looks-good-on-this-site). Once read the edit window help button `?` gives quick reminders of that material. To remove from the screen, click `?` again.

Comment: I have had a look at this. There is a way of using `NonlinarModelfit`. However, your equations are strongly dependant on the range of a so we need an estimate of this value. Can you give us one?

Comment: Is this question of further interest? If yes: The validation('sign check of given data' h[a]>0 &&h[a] <0 && P[a]<0)  of the two modells restricts the  domain of a to ` 1/2 \[Pi]^(1/3) ((R^2 w)/Es)^(1/3)<a< (2 \[Pi])^(1/3) ((R^2 w)/Es)^(1/3)`. Is this restriction meaningful ? Still(!)  information about a is necessary...

Answer (score 2):

The way of solution using NonlinearModelFit is

```
ai=Range[Length[hvec]];
data = Transpose[{ai, hvec  , Pvec  }];
R = 25. 10^-6;
modelh[a_] :=Normal[NonlinearModelFit[data[[All, {1, 2}]],a^2/R - Sqrt[2 Pi a w/Es], {w, Es}, a]]
modelP[a_] :=Normal[NonlinearModelFit[data[[All, {1, 3}]],4 a^3 Es/(3 R) - Sqrt[8 Pi a Es w], {w, Es}, a]]
```

If you're looking for one optimum E*,w for the two models the use of NMinimize is the way to solve the problem (at this point the 'implicit' parameter a is needed, unless you could eleminate a analytically from your two models!)

```
J = Total@Map[(a^2/R - Sqrt[2 Pi a w/Es] - h)^2 + (4 a^3 Es/(3 R) - 
     Sqrt[8 Pi a Es w] - P)^2 /. {a -> #[[1]], h -> #[[2]], 
  P -> #[[3]]} &, data] ;
NMinimize[J, {Es, w}]
```

That's the way to solve your problem, but you have to give additional constraints to Es>0,w>0,...(that's your system knowledge). To get the final result you must adapt parameter a    !

As I mentioned in my comment it is possible to eliminate parameter a, which gives 4 models P[h].

```
R =.
erga = Solve[ a^2/R - Sqrt[2 Pi a w/Es] == h, a] ;
modPh = 4 a^3 Es/(3 R) - Sqrt[8 Pi a Es w] /. erga; (* 4Modells*)
```

NonlinearModelFit can find the optimal Fit

```
hp = Transpose[{hvec, Pvec}];
R = 25. 10^-6;
erg = Table[NonlinearModelFit[hp,   modPhi, {  Es, w}, h],{modPhi,modPh}]
```

and gives 4 FittedModel's. Which branch is the right and plausible one has to be decided...

Comment: But how to get the fitted parameters $E^*$ and $w$? Could we fit the P-h without knowing the data of a? Since it is a parametric variable and the data points for a (avec) is a rough estimation.

Comment: With Fullform[] of the NonlinearModelFit- object you get an expression which includes the values for the parameters E* and w.

Comment: Just one remark: In principle you can solve your first model h==H[a] for a, and substitue a in your second model P=f[a]. In this way you'll get  four possible equations P==F[h] . If you know the right solution branch you can apply NonlinearModelFit directly .

Comment: @ Jack LaVigne The parameter a obviously has a  significance in the way it couples the two models. For a direct solution approach(NMinimize)  it would be helpful to get some information about  a, for example a>0 and/or the ordering of a (a1<a2<...)